# How to use Photoshop or other software to make this kind of picture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, highlighting

Here is the pic:

[image]

Make one part stand out by making the other part grey.

How to do that in Photoshop or other software?

Comment: Its just a gradient effect.  https://www.google.com/#q=gradient+effects+photoshop&safe=off

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way:

1. Open the Image you want in photoshop
2. Add a new layer
3. Fill the layer with Black (Paint bucket)
4. Lower the opacity (In my example 59%)
5. Erase or select delete what you want to be lighter

And you know have an image with a brighter area:

[image]

This is of course highly flexible, if you want the rest of image to be less grayed out, lower the opacity. At 20% opacity for the 2nd layer, it looks like this:

[image]